# How to send each of the strings within a list of strings to a function, and then replace that list element with the list that the function generates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, spacy

```py
import re, spacy

def evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func(input_element):
    #----------------------------------
    #nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm')

    doc = nlp(input_element)  # Your text here
    list_verbs_in_element = []
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ == "VERB": #Only verbs
            start = token.idx  # Start position of token
            end = token.idx + len(token)  # End position = start + len(token)
            list_verbs_in_element.append(token.text)
    #----------------------------------

    return(list_verbs_in_this_input)


#input_list:
list_verbs_in_this_input = ['correr saltar', 'llegamos', 'allí', 'hacía', 'allá', 'en', 'el', 'centro', 'habrá', '']

#call to the function for each element of the list by the return of the function

#remove strings that only have whitespace or are empty

print(list_verbs_in_this_input) # --> print here to check the result
```

I need to send one by one each of the substrings within the list called `list_verbs_in_this_input` to the `evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func()` function, and replace the element(s) of the `list_verbs_in_element` list that is generated in this function by the element from the list `list_verbs_in_this_input` that was sent as a parameter to this function.

[image]

At the end and removing the elements that contain empty strings or only whitespaces, you should get this when printing the original list:

```py
['correr', 'saltar', 'llegamos', 'habrá']
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is non-conventional, and even if it were possible, the resulting code would be much less readable than some other alternatives. A better approach would be to `map` each element in your original list through the function into a list of lists, then use `itertools.chain` to flatten it into a one-dimensional list.

Comment: @Fractalism mmm maybe using itertools is a good option, although I'm not really sure how I would approach it

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, here's a simplified and runnable example of how the code would work using `itertools.chain`:

```py
import re, itertools

def split_string(input_string: str) -> list[str]:
    #----------------------------------
    # process input_element
    substrings = input_string.split(' ')
    #----------------------------------

    return substrings


# input_list
strings = ['correr saltar', 'llegamos', '   ', '']

# list of list of strings
strings_2d = map(split_string, strings)

# flatten strings_1d into a list of verbs
strings_1d = itertools.chain(*strings_2d)

# remove elements that are empty or contain only whitespaces
clean_strings_1d = filter(lambda verb: not re.match(r'^\s*$', verb), strings_1d)

print(list(clean_strings_1d))  # ['correr', 'saltar', 'llegamos']
```

Integrating this into your code, it may look something like this:

(Note that the intermediate results are generators, so you may need to convert them to `list` if you want to use those variables more than once.)

```py
import re, spacy, itertools

def evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func(input_element: str) -> list[str]:
    #----------------------------------
    #nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm')

    doc = nlp(input_element)  # Your text here
    list_verbs_in_element = []
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ == "VERB": #Only verbs
            start = token.idx  # Start position of token
            end = token.idx + len(token)  # End position = start + len(token)
            list_verbs_in_element.append(token.text)
    #----------------------------------

    return list_verbs_in_element


# input_list
list_verbs_in_this_input = ['correr saltar', 'llegamos', 'allí', 'hacía', 'allá', 'en', 'el', 'centro', 'habrá', '']

# list of list of verbs
verbs_2d = map(evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func, list_verbs_in_this_input)

# flatten verbs_2d into a list of verbs
verbs_1d = itertools.chain(*verbs_2d)

# remove elements that are empty or contain only whitespaces
clean_verbs_1d = filter(lambda verb: not re.match(r'^\s*$', verb), verbs_1d)

print(list(clean_verbs_1d)) # --> print here to check the result
```